# Test Cafe Headless Visibility Check

Tags: javascript, typescript, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

When running in headless mode, should the tests make visibilty checks? When I run tests in normal chrome or firefox they all pass, but in headless mode I keep getting this error:

```
test('Assert navigation from Home to page x...', async t => {
await t
    .expect(link.textContent).eql('page x')
    .click(link)
    .expect(getPageUrl()).contains('pagex')
});

Error: The element that matches the specified selector is not visible.
```

and when I add expect([someSelector].visibile).ok() I get this error:

```
   AssertionError: expected false to be truthy
```

I feel my approach to writing these tests for the specific prupose of running them in headless mode is incorrect. I'm not sure if running in headless mode impacts the overall approach to how tests are structured?

I'm writing a number of e2e tests that can integrate into Jenkins so that they run whenever new code is committed.

Answer (score 4):

You want `t.expect(selector.visible).ok()`

Visibility simply checks that the element exists in the DOM and does not have a `visible: hidden` or `display: none` style rule set

Running in headless does not affect this so there might be some other issue.

Comment: I tried that assertion but I get this error when running in headless mode: "   1) AssertionError: expected false to be truthy"
But I don't get any errors when running in normal GUI mode

Comment: It's a bit hard to debug without seeing the page you're testing, is the element your checking initially in the DOM or does it appear after a user action? Can you add a 1 second wait before the visibility check?

Comment: unfortunately, I can't provide the page since its local. I will mention that is written with VueJS and I don't know if that affects how  headless mode tests run?

Comment: It shouldn't, testcafe interacts directly with the DOM so is more or less framework agnostic. e2e tests can be difficult to debug, a good starting point is inspecting the page and targeting elements via ```document.querySelector``` then trying to create a simple isolated test case